# python - pandas groupby to flat DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert groupby result to a flat DataFrame.

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
    "x" : ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B" ,"B"] , 
    "y" : [ 1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6]} )

g1 = df1.groupby(["x"]).max().reset_index()
print(g1)
```

The expected output DataFrame like below:

```
   x  y1 y2 y3
0  A  1  4  0
1  B  2  5  6
2  C  3  0  0
```

If value not exist, use 0 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby.agg` with `add_prefix` and `fillna` with `reset_index`.

Like the following:

```
g1 = df1.groupby('x')['y'].agg(list).agg(pd.Series).add_prefix('y').fillna(0).reset_index()
print(g1)
```

Or if you care about column names, try using `rename` with a slick way with `1 .__add__`:

```
g1 = df1.groupby('x')['y'].agg(list).agg(pd.Series).rename(1 .__add__, axis=1).add_prefix('y').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   x   y1   y2   y3
0  A  1.0  4.0  0.0
1  B  2.0  5.0  6.0
2  C  3.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) index is the 'x' column, and we can use [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) on `x` to enumerate rows to get positional y values as new columns [1,2,3] etc and fill_value of 0 to set the default for missing (benefit of `fill_value` over `fillna` is that `NaN` are not introduced so dtype does not change to float).

Lastly, [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to columns and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to match desired output:

```
out = (
    df1.pivot_table(index='x',
                    columns=df1.groupby('x').cumcount() + 1,
                    values='y',
                    fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('y')
        .reset_index()
)
```

`out`:

```
   x  y1  y2  y3
0  A   1   4   0
1  B   2   5   6
2  C   3   0   0
```